# input type="range" no funciona en calculadora de financiación

Tags: javascript, html, entrada

Buenas estoy haciendo una calculadora en JavaScript de financiación de coches pero no consigo hacer que funcionen los input range bien.
Si que funciona con el value por defecto pero cuando modificas el rango del input no cambian los valores de la calculadora.

Pero si remplazo los input range por inputs de tipo number todo funciona de manera correcta. Al cambiar el valor del input se cambian los resultados de la calculadora.

Os dejo el código haber si alguien puede ayudarme a hacer funcionar los inputs range.

```js
function calculate() {
  //Look up the input and output elements in the document
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  var entry = document.getElementById("entry");
  var apr = document.getElementById("apr");
  var months = document.getElementById("months");
  var payment = document.getElementById("payment");
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
  var totalinterest = document.getElementById("totalinterest");

  // Get the user's input from the input elements.
  // Convert interest from a percentage to a decimal, and convert from
  var principal = parseFloat(amount.value) - parseFloat(entry.value);
  var interest = parseFloat(apr.value) / 100 / 12;
  var payments = parseFloat(months.value);

  // compute the monthly payment figure
  var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments); //Math.pow computes powers
  var monthly = (principal * x * interest) / (x - 1);

  // If the result is a finite number, the user's input was good and
  // we have meaningful results to display
  if (isFinite(monthly)) {
    // Fill in the output fields, rounding to 2 decimal places
    payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
    total.innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
    totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthly * payments) - principal).toFixed(2);
    // Advertise: find and display local lenders, but ignore network errors
    try { // Catch any errors that occur within these curly braces
      getLenders(amount.value, apr.value, months.value);
    } catch (e) { /* And ignore those errors */ }
  } else {
    // Result was Not-a-Number or infinite, which means the input was
    // incomplete or invalid. Clear any previously displayed output.
    payment.innerHTML = ""; // Erase the content of these elements
    total.innerHTML = ""
    totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
    chart(); // With no arguments, clears the chart
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="calculate()">
  <h2>Calculadora de financiacion:</h2>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label>Precio del coche a financiar:</label>
    <input id="amount" value="10000" onkeyup="calculate();">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label>Entrada:</label>
    <input type="range" id="entry" name="entry" onkeyup="calculate();" min="0" max="10000" step="500" value="0">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label>TIN (%):</label>
    <input id="apr" value="7.75" onkeyup="calculate();">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label>Meses:</label>
    <input type="range" id="months" name="months" min="2" max="120" value="60" step="1">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h4>Resultado</h4>
  <div>
    <label>Cuota mensual:</label>
    <span class="output" id="payment"></span> €
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label>Intereses:</label>
    <span class="output" id="totalinterest"> €
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
   <label>Total pagado:</label>
   <span class="output" id="total"></span> €
  </div>
  <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiando el evento `onkeyup()` que tienes sobre el `<input type="range">` por un `oninput()` debería valerte.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function calculate() {
    //Look up the input and output elements in the document
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var entry = document.getElementById("entry");
    var apr = document.getElementById("apr");
    var months = document.getElementById("months");
    var payment = document.getElementById("payment");
    var total = document.getElementById("total");
    var totalinterest = document.getElementById("totalinterest");
    
  // Get the user's input from the input elements.
  // Convert interest from a percentage to a decimal, and convert from
  var principal = parseFloat(amount.value) - parseFloat(entry.value) ;
  var interest = parseFloat(apr.value) / 100 / 12;
  var payments = parseFloat(months.value);
    
  // compute the monthly payment figure
  var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments); //Math.pow computes powers
  var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);

  // If the result is a finite number, the user's input was good and
  // we have meaningful results to display
  if (isFinite(monthly)){
    // Fill in the output fields, rounding to 2 decimal places
    payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
    total.innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
    totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthly*payments)-principal).toFixed(2);
   // Advertise: find and display local lenders, but ignore network errors
   try { // Catch any errors that occur within these curly braces
   getLenders(amount.value, apr.value, months.value);
   }
    
    catch(e) { /* And ignore those errors */ }
   }
   else {
   // Result was Not-a-Number or infinite, which means the input was
   // incomplete or invalid. Clear any previously displayed output.
   payment.innerHTML = ""; // Erase the content of these elements
   total.innerHTML = ""
   totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
   chart(); // With no arguments, clears the chart
   }
  }  

  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="calculate()">
  <h2>Calculadora de financiacion:</h2>
  <br>
  <div>
   <label>Precio del coche a financiar:</label>
   <input id="amount" value="10000" onkeyup="calculate();">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
   <label>Entrada:</label>
   <input type="range" id="entry"  name="entry" oninput="calculate();" min="0" max="10000" step="500" value="0">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
   <label>TIN (%):</label>
   <input id="apr" value="7.75" onkeyup="calculate();">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
   <label>Meses:</label>
   <input type="range" id="months" name="months" min="2" max="120" value="60" step="1"> 
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h4>Resultado</h4>
  <div>
   <label>Cuota mensual:</label>
   <span class="output" id="payment"></span> €
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
   <label>Intereses:</label>
   <span class="output" id="totalinterest"> €
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
   <label>Total pagado:</label>
   <span class="output" id="total"></span> €
  </div>
  <br> 
 </body>
</html>
```